# Программирование на Python создание бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

я новичок о программировании, но крайне заинтересована в этой теме. У меня возникла ошибка при создании бота. я понятия не имею как исправить. делала по курсу, там 0 ошибок учитывая что у меня все идентично.
вот ошибка

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pyt2\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    bot = telebot.MapPractBot('<bot:token>')
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'MapPractBot'
```

вот код

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.MapPractBot('<bot:token>')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет!')

bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В пакете telebot действительно нет такого класса. Замените просто на `telebot.Telebot`.

Answer (score 1):

В `telebot` не существует класса `MapPractBot`, вместо него используется `Telebot`

т.е

```
bot = telebot.Telebot(token)
```

Возможно ваш курс уже устарел